# simplemodal Confirm example wait for return value

Tags: javascript, simplemodal

I have problems with simpleModal confirm example. I want to wait the result as the base confirm dialog and it then take action depending on the button pressed. i do the call in other js. My js code is:

```
 var res = confirm("Delete elements?");

 if (res == true) {
       mainController.deleteNode(nodeMoveMessage, url);
  }
```

and the js that make the dialog is:

```
function confirm(message, callback) {
var modalWindow = document.getElementById("confirm");
console.log(modalWindow);
$(modalWindow).modal({
    closeHTML: "<a href='#' title='Close' class='modal-close'>x</a>",
    position: ["20%",],
    overlayId: 'confirm-overlay',
    containerId: 'confirm-container',
    onShow: function (dialog) {
        var modal = this;

        $('.message', dialog.data[0]).append(message);

        // if the user clicks "yes"
        $('.yes', dialog.data[0]).click(function () {
            // close the dialog
            modal.close(); // or $.modal.close();
            // call the callback
            return true;
        });
    }
});
}
```

the div in my jsp is:

```
    <div id='confirm'>
        <div class='header'><span>Confirm</span></div>
        <div class='message'></div>
        <div class='buttons'>
            <div class='no simplemodal-close'>No</div><div class='yes'>Yes</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have got to add a callback to your modal, so add it first in the `confirm` function:

```
function confirm(message, callback) {
    var modalWindow = document.getElementById("confirm");
    console.log(modalWindow);
    $(modalWindow).modal({
        closeHTML: "<a href='#' title='Close' class='modal-close'>x</a>",
        position: ["20%",],
        overlayId: 'confirm-overlay',
        containerId: 'confirm-container',
        onShow: function (dialog) {
            var modal = this;

            $('.message', dialog.data[0]).append(message);

            $('.yes', dialog.data[0]).click(function () {
                modal.close(); $.modal.close();
                callback(); // HERE IS THE CALLBACK
                return true;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Then you can call the `confirm` function with a callback that executes when the *yes* button is clicked, like this:

```
function doSomething() {
    mainController.deleteNode(nodeMoveMessage, url);
}

confirm("Delete elements?", doSomething);
```

Now when the user clicks the *yes* button the `doSomething` function will be called and the elements will be deleted.